# what's a word for someone who accuses you of something just because they're doing it themselves?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

What's it called when someone blames you or accuses you of doing something because they're doing it themselves? For example, when your boyfriend/girlfriend is cheating on you, so they assume you're also cheating on them. I remember finding a word for it, but I can't seem to find it anymore...

Comment: I added an answer over there because it was missing one word I often use for this: transference